# Print only the list items that contain a certain character

Tags: python, list, python-3.4

I'm trying to increment a count by one, if a string starts with a certain character and it repeats through a string. This is my code

```
def stringMatch(list1, char):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if char == list1[i][:]:
            count = count + 1 
            print(list1[i], count)
```

For the inputs `list1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'corn']` and `char = 'c'`

The output should be

```
cat 1
corn 1
```

Comment: What's that hanging if-statement?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget What do you mean?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's a line in your post that reads `if list1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'corn'] and char = 'c'`, which is not included as part of your code. I therefore do not understand what its purpose is

Comment: I think that's just a "given these inputs" thing.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I made an edit for you, sorry about that

Comment: If you increasing the count, shouldn't it be `corn 2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you use `if char == list1[i][:]`. This causes your problem.

`list1[i][:]` is the same as `list1[i]`, which is really not what you're trying to do. You don't want to see if `list1[i]` is `char`; rather, you want to know if `list1[i]` *contains* `char`. You could accomplish this in many ways. Here are three:

1. `char in list1[i]`
2. this for-loop:

```py
found = False
for c in list1[i]:
    if c == char:
        found = True
        break
```

3. `if any(char==c for c in list1[i])`

In any case, this is what I'd do:

```
def stringMatch(L, char):
    counts = (char in word for word in L)  # compute the counts of `char` in each list item
    for word, count in zip(L, counts):
        if not count: continue
        print(word, count)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why my code was not working perhaps?

Comment: @FriedFish: there! I've added an explanation in my text

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry for all the confusion at the start!

Comment: Method 2 should typically contain a break statement in the if clause, so that it does not unnecessarily keep checking remaining characters.

Comment: Furthermore, the final method that you use also unnecessarily counts the number of occurrences of `char`. The simplest (and therefore pythonic) way of doing what you want to do is definitely your method 1, instead. PS: this is assuming that the question is the title of the question (no counting necessary, count only printed in the original code for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Counting characters in a string is quite easy in python. There is a built in function for counting: `string.count(char)`. Your current method of counting does not work for two reasons.

- The way you check if a letter is in a string does not work. Let's try a test case:

  ```
  >>>'c' == 'cat'[:]
  False
  ```

  Using this method, you are essentially asking if 'c' is equal to the entire string, which is obviously wrong. A better way to do this would be using the `in` keyword. Let's try that with the previous example.

  ```
  >>>'c' in 'cat'
  True
  ```

  So if we were to use this method, we would use the more pythonic `in` keyword. However,we won't need it.
- Assuming that we use the above method (as I've stated above, we won't), there would still be an error in your output. According to your desired output, we are looking to count the characters in each word, yes? However, how you currently have it set up increments the total count variable each time that character is counted. So your output would be:

  ```
  cat 1
  corn 2
  ```

  This is an easy fix. We just have to move the variable inside the for loop so that it resets every time it increments. It would look something like this:

  ```
  for i in list1:
      total = 0
      if char in i:
          total += 1
          print(i, total)
  ```

  However, even then, its not really an accurate loop because we want to count the characters in each word, correct? This (and your own method) only counts if the character exists in the word. Ironically, the `in` keyword doesn't occur in this solution. Instead we need to count each letter of each word to solve this. Here is your new code:

  ```
  for word in list1:
      total = 0
      for letter in word:
          if letter == char:
              total += 1
              print(word, total)
  ```

---

Well, like I stated in the beginning, there is still an easier way. Using the `string.count()` function, the code is now four lines for the entire function. Note, I changed your function name. By convention camelCase is discouraged in python and lowercase/underscore is the convention. Be sure to read [PEP 8, python's style-guide,](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) to learn conventions. Anyways, here is your code:

```
    def string_match(list1, char):
        for i in list1:
            if i.count(char) > 0:
                print(i, i.count(char))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need use a `string.count()`.

```
>>> a = list1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'corn'] 
>>> a = { i:i.count('c') for i in list1 if i.count('c') > 0}
>>> for w in a:
...     print w, a[w]
...  
corn 1
cat 1
```

Comment: any word that does not have the char in it has to be not printed

Comment: Update, didn't notice the expected output before.